# CS50 - week 3 - runoff -My code has a issue

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

This is the code I came up with for the print_winner function in the week 3 assignment of cs50, runoff.
this is my print_winner function.

Print_winner

[image]

It produces some strange behaviour. When the candidate obtains 100% of votes as rank 1, the code works fine. But any less than that the code just keeps on repeating infinitively. I have to use Ctr + c to stop the execution.

For example - ./runoff aa bb cc

if i give 100% of all the first ranks to "cc", it will print the winner correctly as "cc".

[image]

But if I give lets say if i give 2/3 of votes to cc and one vote for another, te codes keeps on looping.

[image]

This is my complete code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
        //debug
        printf("candidate %d %s \n", i,candidates[i].name);
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    //debug -vidu
    for (int ss = 0; ss < voter_count; ss++)
    {
        for (int tt = 0; tt < 3; tt++)
        {
            printf("voter - %d, rank - %d, candidate no - %d \n" , ss, tt, preferences[ss][tt]);
        }
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO //take all these details and enter them to the grid
    int count = 0;
    if (voter < voter_count && rank < 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            //debug
            printf("--name - %s,\n--candidate.name - %s \n", name, candidates[i].name);

            if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
            {
                preferences[voter][rank] = i;

                //debug - print
                printf("voter - %d, rank - %d, total votes - %d, %s \n", voter, rank, i, candidates[i].name);

                count = count + 1;

                return true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    // TODO //take votes from preferences and put it to the candidates

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            //check for the index no of preferences first candidate
            if (preferences[i][0] == j && candidates[j].eliminated == false)
            {
                candidates[j].votes = candidates[j].votes + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    //debug = print the canditate table
    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
    {
        printf("DEBUG in vote = Candid name - %s, Index no - %d, votes - %d \n",candidates[k].name, k,candidates[k].votes);
    }

    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO //If any candidate has more than half of the vote, their name should be printed and the function should return//if not false
    //debug = print the canditate table
    for (int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
    {
        printf("DEBUG in print_winner = Candid name - %s, Index no - %d, votes - %d \n",candidates[k].name, k,candidates[k].votes);
    }

    int kk = 0;

    //devide by total and
    for (int j=0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        kk = candidates[j].votes/voter_count * 100;
        //debug
        printf("candidate %d candidates[j].votes - %d \n", j, candidates[j].votes);
        printf("candidate %d kk - %d \n", j, kk);
        if (kk > 50)
        {
            printf("the winner is %s \n", candidates[j].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    // TODO
    //bubble sort
    for (int step = 0; step < candidate_count; step++)
    {
        // loop to compare array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < (candidate_count - 1); i++)
        {
            // compare two adjacent elements, change > to < to sort in descending order
            if (candidates[i].votes > candidates[i + 1].votes)
            {
                // swapping occurs if elements are not in the intended order
                candidate temp = candidates[i];
                candidates[i] = candidates[i + 1];
                candidates[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return candidates[0].votes;

}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == candidates[i + 1].votes && candidates[i].votes == min && candidates[i].votes == candidates[candidate_count].votes)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This may be the first instance that I've seen of someone posting code for cs50 that is not painful to read!  Well done.  This may seem like a trivial detail, but you should really get in the habit of writing error messages to stderr.  It may seem that it doesn't matter now, since you probably have both stdout and stderr going to the same place, but you should internalize the idea that error messages go to stderr.  eg `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid vote.\n");`

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues, but one that jumps out is:

```
kk = candidates[j].votes/voter_count * 100;
```

Since both variables on the right hand side are of type `int`, the division is integer division.  Since `voter_count` is always greater than or equal to `candidates[j].votes`, the value of `kk` is always either `0` or `100`.  To get floating point results, you could use:

```
kk = ((double)candidates[j].votes / (double)voter_count) * 100;
```

(Both casts aren't strictly necessary, and neither are the outer parens; that's a stylistic choice.)